R Plotly Animation Speed
I'm in the process of creating an animation with R Plotly. I'm trying to make my animation play at a certain speed, however, having spent some time playing with the frame parameter, I can't seem to create any effect that isn't overcome by the size of the data I'm animating.
For example, two animations with frame values and numbers of frames that I would think cancel each other out such that these animation play for the same amount of time do not, presumably only due to the size of their data:
plot_ly(data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10, xend = 10:1, yend = 10:1, f = 1:10)) %>%
  add_lines(x = ~c(x, xend), y = ~c(y, yend), frame = ~c(f, f)) %>%
  animation_opts(frame = 10, easing = 'cubic-in-out')

plot_ly(data.frame(x = 1:100, y = 1:100, xend = 100:1, yend = 100:1, f = 1:100)) %>%
  add_lines(x = ~c(x, xend), y = ~c(y, yend), frame = ~c(f, f)) %>%
  animation_opts(frame = 1, easing = 'cubic-in-out')

It is/was my assumption that the total length of the animation would be determined by the number of frames, times the frame duration (whatever is passed to animation_opts) that doesn't seem to be the case. It seems that there's something else restricting or controlling the total length of the animation.
Should 100 frames at 1 millisecond each play for the same amount of time as 10 frames played for 10 milliseconds each?
I did find this post that suggests changing the resolution, but I don't know if that applies to non-map traces (I couldn't find that argument for scatter traces in the documentation).
Is there anyway I can dictate the duration of the frames regardless of the number of frames to be animated (or even the total length of the animation, so that I can adjust that according to my desired number of frames and frame duration)? Ultimately, I want to be able to make animations with more frames play faster, at the (total) speed that I can only seem to be achieve with fewer frames.
Thanks for any help!

I guess plotly won't be able to display animations with a frame rate of 1 ms due to technological limitations (browser). Try setting frame = 1000 and frame = 100and both animations will last about 10 seconds.
